# Will Pagiante gem is limiting count results in loop to the per page number, how to avoid?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, will-paginate

I do this in my controller:

```
@orders_e = Order.all.where(seller: current_user).where(order_status: [2] ).paginate(:page => params[:month_orders_page_1], :per_page => 12)
@orders_month = @orders_e.all.group_by { |mon|  mon.created_at.beginning_of_month }
```

and then this in my view:

```
<% @orders_month.each do |month, orders| %>
     <td><%= month.strftime("%b.") %></td>
     <td class="center"><%= orders.count %></td>
<% end %>
```

and the results get capped at 12. For instance, if there are 20 `@orders_e` that month, it will only count up to the 12 mark.

When I take the paginate code off the end of the controller code, it doesn't do it, but the front end will have unlimited results.

I could cap the loop at 12, but I want to have 12 results per page.

In what way can I make it so I have 12 results per page with a pagination feature, with or without the will_paginate gem?

(I did tag javascript in case there is a way to do it through javascript.)

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Do you want to paginate your ungrouped `@orders_e` or your grouped orders within `@orders_month`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use 2 separate requests just to show the total count.

```
# controller code
scope = Order.where(seller: current_user, order_status: [2] )

@orders_e = scope.paginate(page: params[:month_orders_page_1], per_page: 12)
@order_counts = scope.group("DATE_PART('month', created_at)").count

# view code
<% @order_counts.each do |month, count| %>
  <td><%= Date::MONTHNAMES[month.to_i] %></td>
 <td class="center"><%= count %></td>
<% end %>
```